# Pycharm not show out put in the case of Numpy (Google colab show)

Tags: python, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmXt1.png)

In the case of the pycharm, it doesn't show any output.

I used "print()" already. But, Pycharm is showing the <numpy.vectorize object at 0x0000022CF6EDDFA0>.

Comment: Please include your code as formatted text and not as an image. Looks like you are printing the vectorize object and not the result of calling the vectorize object - `print(aa([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))`

Comment: It is working as expected. What you are seeing is the string representation of the aa object obtained from __repr__() function. That's what print does. But most likely you wanted to do something else since you are printing the vectorize object itself and not the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"aa" in your code is a vectorized function object.

Like any other function or object, when you do `print(aa),` you aren't calling it. Similarly, if you write `print(len)`, you get basic description of the function len: `<built-in function len>`. In order to actually call it, it needs to be followed by brackets. For example: `print(len('hello'))`

In your code, you probably need `print( aa([1,2,3,4], 2) )`